# Deleting VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I want to delete my entire VirtualBox, which I have been working on, because I am
giving away my PC. How should I do that? I am working on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Why do you only want to delete the VirtualBox?  Why not wipe the whole hard drive, which could contain traces of your private information scattered in temp files, the swap file, and even in deleted files which may potentially be recovered.

Answer (score 5):

To be honest, if I was in your shoes, I'd wipe the whole disk before giving it away. I'm guessing there's a lot more info on the drives that I wouldn't want shared than some VMWare images.

To make it easy, there's [DBAN](http://www.dban.org/download) or you can run Ubuntu and have it wipe your disk.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall the program, and choose to delete all images (or do that separately).

Comment: Doesn't uninstalling the program already delete all images?

Comment: I am not sure if that is the default, but it is an option.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall the program as you normally would, then go to C:\Users\YourName\VirtualBox VMs. There you will find all the files and images Virtualbox stores. On x64 Windows, you have to do this or else they will remain.

Uninstallation can be done through Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution is to create a new Windows user and then delete your old user. This will delete all the personal information associated with the old account including all VirtualBox virtual disks. Personally, if I was giving my computer away, I would wipe the whole disk just to be safe.